# How to find a word left of a specific word if it exists else return the last word in regex

Tags: regex, string

For example,

```
MR-L6LQN-LP MR-L6LQN-LQ Way
```

should return `MR-L6LQN-LQ` here the specific word is `'Way'`
if the string is

```
MR-L6LQN-LP MR-L6LQN-LQ
```

output should be

```
MR-L6LQN-LQ
```

I think lookahead ideas would come in handy but am not able to work it out. Please suggest regex only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with a positive lookahead:

```
\b[A-Z0-9-]+(?=\s+Way|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zdz8TU/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b`: Assert word boundary
- `[A-Z0-9-]+`: Match one or more of uppercase letters, digits or hyphens
- `(?=\s+Way|$)`: Positive Lookahead to assert we have spaces and `Way` ahead or end of line.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks.